# How to call a function/sub procedure of VBS from command line?

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I am trying to automate Outlook desktop app. I have different sub procedures written in a vb script file (file.vbs) which performs different kinds of operations on Outlook. I want to call one of the sub procedures from the command line. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example calls function or sub and finds the right call dynamically. On command line you provide 'functionToExecute' as the name of the function you like to call or 'subToExecute' as the subroutine you like to call. Two examples for calling the VBS from the command line for a sub and a function respectively:

```
cscript.exe demo.vbs subToExecute
cscript.exe demo.vbs functionToExecute
```

In the VBS script get the name of the routine from the command line argument and decide whether to call a subroutine or call a function:

```
On Error Resume Next
mySubOrFuncName = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)  'name of the subroutine or function
subCall = "call " & mySubOrFuncName & "()"
Execute subCall

If Err.Number <> 0 Then  'if sub could not be called, take the function call
  eval(mySubOrFuncName)
  Err.Clear
End If

WScript.Quit

'this is a subroutine you already have
Sub subToExecute
   MsgBox "inside a sub"
   'do stuff
End Sub

'this is a function you already have
Function functionToExecute
   MsgBox "inside a function"
   'do stuff
End Function
```

Handy example for VBS command line handling: https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-args.html

Comment: This helped me. But as you mentioned, eval() didn't work for me.

Comment: @user8533698 `Eval()` evaluates a condition it cannot execute full statements, you should use `Execute()` / `ExecuteGlobal()` instead. Also, the example above will cause a syntax error because of the incorrect string assigned to `a`. Don't accept incomplete / wrong answers it helps no one.

Comment: just corrected the syntax error in assignment to `a`

Comment: Removing the " does not make this 'answer' correct. It still uses the wrong routine (Eval instead of Execute), the wrong names (MyFunc vs functionToExecute), and the wrong strategy (dynamic execution vs conditionals). Not understanding the difference between Subs and Functions doesn't help any, either.

Comment: provided a working example finally